# Is there a rule to know whether a verb needs an er to indicate an agent noun or doesn’t need it?

Tags: nouns, suffixes

I know that most of verbs can be transformed into noun or thing, which does the action.

But why are there many words that stay as they are and the suffix “er” cannot be attached to them.

For instance,

Teach ———-> teacher

Seek—————> seeker

Kill——————> killer

But the following noun stay as they are

> - Judge————> judge (the person who judge)
> - Guide ————> guide (the person who guide)
> - Delegate ———> delegate (the person who is delegated)

Why these nouns, for example, don’t turn into:

> - 1) judger
> - 2) guider
> - 3) delegator

Is there any rule to follow to determine whether a verb takes er or stays as it is to convey the meaning of a person doing that specific job or action?

Comment: In the case of delegate, those are homographs only in some dialects. The final vowel sound is a schwa in the noun, and [eɪ] (the vowel in 'say') in the verb. Also, a delegate isn't the agent for the verb *to delegate*, they are the one who is delegated to. *Delegator* is attested, as one who delegates.

Comment: I thought this might be a result of the different origins of English words - for instance, *judge*, *guide* and *delegate* all came to English through French or Latin, while *teach*, *seek* and *kill* are Germanic.  However, there are counter examples: French view/viewer, dance/dancer and Germanic cook/cook.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, this is just a matter of knowing the vocabulary. The *-er*/*-or* form is used when there is no distinct word for the agent.

Answer (score 1):

There is no learnable rule.  In all the cases you give, the noun is very old and (in the case of delegate and guide) the noun predates the verb.  Thus the verb "to guide" is derived from the noun (or both are derived from the same Old French source)

Delegate (and many other noun/verb pairs) is distinguished by stress. The stress being at the start of the word in the noun, and at the end in the verb.

In the case of "Judge", the verb is older, but the noun form had influences from Latin *iudex*.  This is a very old word and the exact process of coinage is rather uncertain. It is known as a surname before it was known as a common noun, and the form "judgeman" may have existed too.

So these words tend to very old words, and in many cases the verb was formed from the noun, or alongside it. But learners simply have to learn these words as special cases.  There is no logic that can tell you from the form or meaning that "builder" takes "-er", whereas "chairperson" or "chair" is never a "chairer".